# Save X-Cart cart

Tags: email, session, save, checkout, x-cart

So what I need is to somehow save the x-cart cart, and basically save this cart not in cookies but in server side session, but databases, so that if a client has filled the checkout form in, but never checkedout, to then email the user saying something like, "Have you forgotten to pay?" or something. I hope you get what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this.
[abandoned cart reminder module for xcart](http://www.x-cart.com/extensions/modules/abandoned-cart-reminder.html)

Its not free but like any other xcart module you wont find them for free xD